# Number typing issue on RedHat

Tags: linux, terminal, tabs, redhat-enterprise-linux

When typing `4` or `6` on terminal window it changes the tab instead of writing the number. I am using `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.4 (Santiago)`. How can this issue be fixed?

Here are answers to Rik's questions

- I am using console
- In **configure shortcuts** there is only **Switch to Tab 6** action which contains 6 character
- I can type 6 in all other applications I have tried.
- I am using bash
- After `bind -p | grep 6` there is `"6": self-insert`
- `8` and `2` doesn't scroll. It prints the symbol as expected.
- In `csh` the problem is same
- In `gnome-terminal` `6` is printed

Comment: Curious. 4 is left and 6 is right on function keyboard. If you type 'ctrl + v' before the key you can see the code associated. You can try just to see if 6 is right arrow '^[[C' or actual six.

Comment: After ctrl + v it doesn't show any code but changes the tab.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something in your keybinding is messed up.
If you're on KDE, could you check the following: (If you're on Gnome, let me know)

- In the terminal screen goto `Settings`
- Choose `Edit Current Profile`
- Goto the `Keyboard`-tab
- `Edit` the default
- Type in the textarea a `6` in the `Input`-box

What output do you get in `Output`-box? It should say `6`.
If you got a `6` somewhere in the left column in that list above that, it doesn't belong there.

## Edit:

If you get the `input/output` boxes you **are** probably using `Konsole` from `Kde`.

Some follow-up questions (you can [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/651433/edit) your question with the answers):

- Are you indeed using `Konsole`? Check `Help>About ???`.
- If it is `Konsole`: Could you check `Settings>Configure shortcuts`? Is there a `6` (you can type `6` in the search to get all the `6`'s).
- I take it you can type the `6`'s in all other applications?
- Are you using a desktop or laptop?
- What shell are you using? (You can type `echo $0` to determine if `bash`, `ksh` etc...)
- If in `bash`: could you do a `bind -p | grep 6`? You need to paste the `6` from another application because you can't type it. Is there a `"6": self-insert`?
- Do the `8` and the `2` do something? (Like scrolling up/down if you have enough lines in terminal) Or do they work properly?
- You could try a different shell. If you're in `ksh` try typing `bash` + <kbd>enter</kbd>
  If you're in `bash` try typing `ksh` <kbd>enter</kbd>. (or other combination)
- And last (I know, it's a lot :)
  If you start the `gnome-terminal` (if it is still installed) can you type the `6`?

Comment: After entering 6 in input the output was 6 too. It doesn't help after adding (6, 6) row on table

Comment: I added some follow-up questions in my answer. I know it's a lot, but hey, that's troubleshooting. (you can [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/651433/edit) your question with the answers)

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: I don't know `console`. I only have `konsole` and `gnome-terminal`. In `konsole` you switch between tabs with Shift+Right and Left. It could be your `console` mixes some keys up. (What happens if you do a Shift+Right ?) You could try to re-install the package for `console`. I think it is a problem with the package itself or the keybinding in that package because it only happens there.

Answer (score 0):

As rik quoted the problem appears to be at keybinding,one of the solution can be checking the events which are mapped for the keybinding

You can modify the key-bindings for gnome-terminal using [gconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor).

Look under: **apps/gnome-terminal/keybindings**

start `gconf-editor` and navigate to  **/apps/gnome-terminal/keybindings/help**

Browse move tab left and move tab right and also check whether numpadkeys were mapped for changing tabs,if the keys were mapped change it accordingly

Sample Example for disabling a tab change can be found over [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37313/how-do-i-deactivate-f1-and-f10-keybindings-in-gnome-terminal).

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for answer but I didn't find bindings for 4 or 6 there